# Is that different to write an applet working with NFC?

Tags: applet, nfc, javacard

My question is in two parts:

1-From applet point of view, does it differ to write an applet to work with mobile NFC? if so, what are the differences?

2-what changes are required (I mean Global Platform environment) to be done in order to communicate with the applet using mobile NFC?

My Target is to write an applet and access it using *Single Wire Protocol* (SWP) of mobile connected to NFC antenna. Is there any previously done project I can learn from? Where is the point to begin this?